# how to search for a word in a sentence, but ignore it if it's part of another word in python

Tags: python, search

so one of my friends built a CPPS (club penguin private server) and built a swear filter for it in python, but requested I take a look at it because it needed an update. However, I have found that he entered some alternatives like FAK, and this means that when you type FAKE, it kicks you for swearing. How can I search for ONLY the word, and ignore it if it's part of another word, or do I need to add a spare list of words to ignore?
(quick note, the code seen below is what I assume you need, but some of it is for connecting to the database or the client instead, so rework it as necessary, I just need the line for either ignoring fake, or making sure it's only the word on screen and not part of another word)
thanks

the best I've got so far was to completely remove the FAK from his database, but that just let people run wild with what they said.

```
@Handlers.Throttle(0.5)
def handleSendMessage(self, data):
    if data.Id != self.user.ID:
        return self.transport.loseConnection()
badWords = ["fak"]

    for badWord in badWords:
        badWord = badWord.upper()
        if badWord in data.Message.upper():
            return self.server.players[self.user.ID].sendErrorAndDisconnect(800)
    self.room.sendXt("sm", self.user.ID, data.Message)
```

I expect that the code, when initiated on his CPPS, will be able to detect whether what the person has said is actually swearing, or whether they're just saying something that has the letters of that word in it.

Comment: just check if previous character before word and next character after word is space.

Comment: You should try some NLP libraries. Such requirements are usually handled with ML models!?

Comment: Have you tried appending a whitespace character to each side of the bad words?

Answer (score 0):

```
import re

pattern = '|'.join(fr'\b{word}\b' for word in badwords)
if re.search(pattern, data.Message.casefold()):
    return self.server.players[self.user.ID].sendErrorAndDisconnect(800)
```